# Creating CSV file through Visualforce and apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm getting a list of data from salesforce in apex class and when i'm trying to display in .CSV format i'm getting issue with the downloaded CSV (it's not having a proper format)

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="Export_1_cls" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" contentType="text/csv#test1.csv">
<apex:dataTable value="{!listofcols}" var="t">
    <apex:column headerValue="{!t}"/>
</apex:dataTable> 
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class Export_1_cls{
public list<string> listofcols{get;set;}
    public Export_1_cls(){
        for(intger i=0;i<=5;i++){
             listofcols.add('column Header'+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific than that.  What is the 'proper format' you're expecting?  What is actually happening? What do you want to happen?

Comment: @NickCook If you execute my code, it will gives you a file with corrupted data. My requirement is to list the available column headers in CSV format

Comment: If you want a `csv`, you need to output data joined with comma (`,`) and newline (`\n`) characters, not a `dataTable`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Would you provide me any example plz

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to do this is to just build a CSV in memory and just output the raw string.

```
<apex:page controller="Export_1_cls" showHeader="false" 
    sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" 
contentType="text/csv#test1.csv">{!csvString}</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class Export_1_cls{
    public String getCsvString() {
        String[] rows = new String[0];
        String[] line = new String[0];

        for(integer i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            line.add('column '+i);
        }
        rows.add(String.join(line, ','));
        // Build other rows

        return String.join(rows,'\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, almost verbatim what I was in the middle of typing up.

Comment: don't forget to use `esacpeCsv()` on all cell values in case they have embedded comma or double quote